# What is meant by d=θ(N) in terms of a d-heap where N is the number of elements?

Tags: data-structures

**Problem I want to solve:** if you have to do M percolations and N deleteMins on a d-heap that initially has N elements. What is the running time for d=θ(N)?

I am confused by what d=θ(N) means. θ is supposed to represent average case running time, but in this case it is used to represent the value of d.

**My question:** I am assuming this mean d = N so that would mean the actual heap is simply one root with all other elements connected to that one root. Is my interpretation accurate?

Answer (score 0):

Big-theta notation is often used for asymptotic running time, but it's just a relationship between values and functions, and can be used in other contexts as well.

*d=θ(N)* means that there are constants *a* and *b* such that, when *N* is big enough, *aN < d < bN*

Obviously, you can't have *d > N* in this case, since the heap only has *N* elements, but that *a* constant can be arbitrarily small.  You could have *d = 0.1N*, for example.

The phrasing of the question suggests that the asymptotic running time will be the same no matter what these constants *a* and *b* are, which is a pretty big hint as to what the answer is.  You can assume that *d = N*, for example, and then check to make sure you get the same answer when *d = 0.1N*.